# Validation constraints on form fields ignored

Tags: 8, forms

Trying to figure out custom validation with constraints, but no luck yet. Right now, my form posts content and gives no errors when form is filled out incorrectly.

(Please avoid suggesting validation modules -- I know those exist.)

Maybe somebody knows what I'm missing? Or maybe it's done different when I'm doing specific fields? Or maybe this isn't how to do it on a back-end content submission form?  Here's what I have so far:

I built a module called "custom_validation." It contains custom_validation.module:

```
  <?php

/**
 * @file
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_type_alter().
 */
function custom_validation_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {

  /** @var $entity_types \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface[] */

  $entity = $entity_types['node'];
  $entity->addConstraint('BlogpostError');
}
```

Then, in subfolder src/Plugin/Validation/Constraint, I've got two files. 
BlogpostErrorConstraint.php contains:

```
namespace Drupal\custom_validation\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * Prevent article creation if errors.
 *
 * @Constraint(
 *   id = "BlogpostError",
 *   label = @Translation("Added blog post category instead of story author in author field", context = "Validation"),
 *   type = "string"
 * )
 */
class BlogpostErrorConstraint extends Constraint {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */      

    public $notByline = '%value is a blog post type. Please add a byline';

    public $noImageSource = 'need image source';

}
```

BlogpostErrorConstraintValidator.php contains:

```
namespace Drupal\custom_validation\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

/**
 * Validates the BlogpostError constraint.
 */
class BlogpostErrorConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validate($items, Constraint $constraint) {

    if (!isset($items)) {
      return;
    }

    // limit this to 'blog entries' content type
    if ($items->bundle() == 'blog_entry') {

      // now loop through each field...
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        // an array of phrases we don't want in the field
        $bad_bylines = [];
        array_push($bad_bylines,"Value one","value two","abc123");

        // adding validation...
        //byline field
        if (in_array($item['field_byline'], $bad_bylines)) {
           // not sure of syntax here
           $this->context->addViolation($constraint->notByline, ['%value' => $item->value]);
        }

        //main image source field...
        if ($item['field_main_image_source'] == '') {
           $this->context->addViolation($constraint->noImageSource, ['%value' => $item->value]);
        }
      }

    } 

  } 

}
```

Comment: Is that a typo, or does your file's name start with a lowercase 'b'? Talking about blogpostErrorConstraint.php

Comment: just a typo. the file is BlogpostErrorConstraint.php - I just corrected it

Comment: All right. Is the code you have in the validate() function complete or is there more to it?

Comment: Yes, that's complete. It's just a starting point as I try and figure out how it works.

Comment: Well, that won't really work that well and it's not even a problem of implementing the Validation API. The code has several problems and needs to be revised, e.g. `$items` comes out of nowhere, `if ($field['field_main_image_source'] = '')` performs an assignment and not a comparison, and so on. Try to revise and update your question once the code is in order and it does come down to the Validation API. So far as I have tried your code locally, it does hook into the Validation API properly.

Comment: I think you should add the validation to fields not content entity as per this guide https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint Also your second if statement contains single equal sign

Comment: Actually, that is the guide I referenced. I've made a couple edits above, but still trying to learn and figure out what I've done wrong. I'll edit again once / if I figure out more

Comment: Making some progress. At this point, I think I need to figure out how to get the field label out of each $item, so I can start validating, right?

Comment: There is a lot of code here. First step I would advise is to step through it with xdebug to determine where its failing, and potentially, why.

Comment: Aside from debugging it, are you using the right hook? The referenced guide uses `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter`, not `hook_entity_type_alter`. Also the id and the class name of the constraint differ, which may also be a potential issue.

Comment: @Kevin The current code seems to work, using the `hook_entity_type_alter` (thought the same); I tested it locally and XDebug brings me inside the `BlogpostErrorConstraintValidator ::validate()` function when saving a node form.

Comment: new day, starting to look at this again. Without xdebug, I can see that I need to change up the "$field[]" bit. I'm trying to figure out how to get the field name out of $item that gets looped. For now, I'll stay with hook_entity_type_alter, as @StefanosPetrakis says it seems to be working.

Comment: on a side note I don't think xdebug is feasible to install on the environment I'm using. Security permissions issue. Maybe Devel covers my needs? I have that.

Comment: Yeah.. I may have to tackle another project. This one's over my head and experience level. I got as far as the above modified code giving me an invalid argument exception. "Unable to get a value with a non-numeric delta in a list. (line 98 of ... ItemList.php) Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was trying too hard. Typical beginner mistake. :)  I threw out the code above, and started from scratch. I replaced everything with the code examples in this tutorial: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint

Within the validator, I replaced `if (!is_int($item->value))` with  `if ($item->value == "Value one" || "value two")`, to get what I needed to validate on. Then I modified the variable names, field names and error messages to suit my needs. It only handles one field, but gets me closer to what I need.

Comment: But `$item->value = "Value one"` is still an assignment... you'd want `if ($item->value == "Value one" || $item->value == "value two")` to do a comparison.

Comment: ok... just tested with that correction, and it's working. I modified the text above to reflect the correction.

Comment: For the `if` statement `$item->value == "Value one" || "value two"` is equivalent to `TRUE`.

Comment: Correct. I want it to be true if it's value one or value two. If it's not, then false. There's probably a better way of doing this. In the code I first posted, I was trying to see if the field value was in an array of unwanted values, else true. The above is working for me as the same thing, without an array to check, and I didn't want to 'rock the boat' for the moment.

Comment: Isn't that just saying "OR [anything]"? It's true so long as its not literally `FALSE`. If you are looking for value and type, use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: ah dang.. I see what you're saying now. It also thinks it's an error when the field contains a name not 'value one' or 'value two' ... Damn. Just when I thought I had this. It's doing it, regardless of == or ===

Comment: Ok.. yeah. I'm back to square one. The above solution is no good and I'm not understanding something fundamentally about how to do this, even though it seems like exactly what I need. I can't even use an array, it completely ignores that.

Comment: What the heck!??? I can't even get this to work with something as simple as "if (strpos($item->value, 'Value one') !== false) {" . Please somebody just tell me what the heck I'm missing so I can get past this thing and learn from it?

Comment: This is why you need a debugger... so you can step through line by line and inspect scope.

Comment: bummer.. I'm using Acquia Dev Destop - on a mac. Acquia's instructions for adding xdebug are for windows only. I tried anyway, and it didn't seem to work. UPDATE: and, they only have xdebug for PHP 5. not included for 7