# file name constraint in form

Tags: 8, forms

I've got a basic field constraint figured out (per question here: [Validation constraints on form fields ignored](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273527/validation-constraints-on-form-fields-ignored/273586#273586) )

Next, I want to constrain the main image field to limit the file name. For example, if someone uploads a file named "1234-shutterstock.jpg" I want to detect that the file name contains "shutterstock" and add that violation.

But I have no clue how to tackle the syntax for this. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

I've started with something like this. I know this is wrong.

```
            <?php   
            namespace Drupal\custom_validation\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

            use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
            use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

            /**
             * Validates the Image constraint.
             */
            class MainImageConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

              /**
               * {@inheritdoc}
               */
              public function validate($items, Constraint $constraint) {
                foreach ($items as $item) {   
                  if (strpos($item->value, 'shutterstock') !== false) {
                    $this->context->addViolation($constraint->wrongImageName, ['%value' => $item->value]);
                  }

                }
              }

            }
```

Comment: Try `$item->entity->filename->value` in the `strpos`

Comment: Perfect! I didn't think it was gonna be that easy!

Answer (score 0):

Per Clive's comment above, it works with this:

```
        namespace Drupal\custom_validation\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

        use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
        use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

        /**
         * Validates the Image constraint.
         */
        class MainImageConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

          /**
           * {@inheritdoc}
           */
          public function validate($items, Constraint $constraint) {
            foreach ($items as $item) {   
              if (strpos($item->entity->filename->value, 'shutterstock') !== false) {
                $this->context->addViolation($constraint->wrongImageName, ['%value' => $item->value]);
              }

            }
          }

        }
```

Comment: This is missing the pattern match on the value?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding the question? I added in your $item->entity->filename->value, and it does exactly what I want.

Comment: `if ($item->entity->filename->value, 'shutterstock') !== false)` how does that work? Nothing is being evaluated.

Comment: I'll have to research to understand better. I assume it's in the core ConstraintValidator that this class is extending? and/or the other files that I didn't include from the module, as I didn't think they were necessary to show. At this moment, all I can say is it's doing exactly what I want.

Comment: It’s in the code you posted in the answer that you say works. You’re not doing a strpos or preg_match or anything on the value - so how does this work?

Comment: Ahhhh! Now I see what you're saying. Sorry! I didn't see that I'd overwritten the strpos in the answer when copy-pasting it from Cole's comment into the answer! I've edited to reflect that correctly.